# What's the most performant and non-repetitive way to instantiate 20+ child classes when all classes have 2 of the same constructors

Tags: c#, .net, performance, inheritance, instantiation

I have a structure where an Abstract Base Class, let's call it Animal Inherits from the interface IAnimal. It has two constructors one to create a new animal in memory and one to read one in from an XMLReader:

```cs
public interface IAnimal
{
  uint NrOfLimbs {get; set;}
  string PackName {get; set;}
  //Enum of all currently possible types
  eAnimalType Type {get;}
}
```

```cs
public abstract class Animal : IAnimal
{
  uint NrOfLimbs {get; set;}
  string PackName {get; set;}
  eAnimalType Type {get;}
  
  internal Animal(uint nrOfLimbs, string packName, eAnimalType type)
  {
    NrOfLimbs = nrOfLimbs;
    PackName = packName;
    Type = type
  }

  internal Animal(string packName, XmlReader xr)
  {
    //Error/null checking should be here but skipping for question brevity.
    nrOfLimbs = xr.GetAttribute("nrOfLimbs");
    Type = xr.GetAttribute("type");
  }

  //Other base/abstract methods etc.
}
```

Then we have a Whole Lot of animal classes based on the eAnimalType enum.
for a basic example looking like this:

```cs
public class Monkey: Animal
{
  public bool hasTail = false;
 
  internal Monkey(uint nrOfLimbs, string packName, eAnimalType type) : 
  base(nrOfLimbs, packName, type)
  {
  }

  internal Monkey(string packName, XmlReader xr) :
  base(packName, xr)
  {
    hasTail = xr.GetAttribute("hasTail");
  }

  //Other potential methods etc.
}
```

Each of the 20+ animal classes have the exact same input variables in these two constructors. And their own individual public interfaces. Most of which only inherit the IAnimal interface and add no new properties or methods with very few exceptions.

We also have a collection class holding a List of Animal called _animals and a Factory class that is supposed to create different animals based on type and insert them into that list.

Which leads to my question how do I most efficently instantiate new animals using these two create methods:

```cs
internal static class AnimalFactory
{
 public static Animal Create(uint nrOfLimbs, string packName, eAnimalType type)
 {
 }

 public static Animal Create(string packName, XmlReader xr)
 {
 }
}
```

I could have a switch case with a new call for each individual animal type like so:

```cs
internal static class AnimalFactory
{
 public static Animal Create(uint nrOfLimbs, string packName, eAnimalType type)
 {
   switch(eAnimalType)
   {
     case eAnimalType.Monkey:
      return new Monkey(nrOfLimbs, packName, type);
     case eAnimalType.Dog:
      return new Dog(nrOfLimbs, packName, type);
     //... Repeat ad-infinitum for each eAnimalType.
   }
 }
}
```

But this hardly feels efficent. Especially considering i'd need a separate switch case or an If-statement in every case depending on the constructor.

Naturally the best way would probably be to refactor the whole thing. Having so many individual child-classes with so many similarities mostly differing on an enum type can be solved more elegantly a number of ways.

Unfortunately that would introduce breaking changes as the child classes are public and in-use so its just not an option at this stage.

So the 20+ classes need to remain. In addition this needs to be compatible with .net 3.5

I've looked into a number of options but while reflection via Type and Type.GetConstructor or pre-compiled Expression Trees are possible they are considerably less performant than calling New directly in a switch case. Also looked into an Abstract Factory Pattern which could MAYBE work but in the end it looks like I'm going to run into the same enum * 2 switch case problem at runtime.

So while two switch-cases or switch-case with an If in each case is a hassle and seems to have code-smell it seems like the only option.

Is this true? It feels silly, it's two constructors with the exact same input in every class case. Surely there's a better solution? I keep feeling like I've heard of some pattern or logic which works well for this but I just can't find it.

Ideally I'd just like to have the two Create functions reference a singular method to get the appropriate child class and make a new call with the appropriate constructor from there as the Create function already knows what constructor it wants to use.

Is there a more simple or performant solution out there? I feel like this must be deceptively simple but I just can't see it.

Comment: While you might be able to find another solution that "looks cool" and/or uses lesser-known language features, keeping the switch cases you already have is almost certainly the best solution. It's easy to read, and anyone with any programming experience will be able to understand it. Yes, it looks ugly, but sometimes that's just what you need.

Comment: @MosheKatz I suppose that's true! It just feels like so many unnecesarily many lines and numerous in case changes need to be made in the future to the inputs. Since I'm not all that experienced a developer (just a few years) I figured I might be missing something. Thanks Moshe!

Comment: Source generator might work.